# SASS / SCSS, compose variable value dynamically (using also Bootstrap maybe)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass, bootstrap-4

I have a `[data-class="danger"]`

and I need to interpolate this `danger` variable in my scss variable value property.

My code:

```
.btn[data-class="danger"] {

  background: $brand-#{attr(data-class)};

}
```

`$brand-danger` is a Bootstrap variable.

**How to do?**

Comment: John, can't you simplify your selector to .btn-danger { background: $brand-danger }; ?  Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but bootstrap4 _variables.scss file shows $brand-danger: $red !default; and in turn _buttons.scss uses this in the class: .btn-danger {
  @include button-variant($btn-danger-color, $btn-danger-bg, $btn-danger-border);
}

Comment: Sorry, I missed adding _variables.scss sets $btn-danger-bg:                  $brand-danger !default;
$btn-danger-border:              $btn-danger-bg !default;

Comment: Dear @Eggs, thanks for your answer, I don't want new classes if I already have these... no? DRY. Because I use "danger, "warning", "success" and so on...